# Can't use more than one combo box on excel

Tags: excel, vba, list, combobox, dynamic-list

I have made two active X combo boxes for a list of 220 sites. Before making the active x combo box i have made a sheet that searches through my data and finds the sites that match with what i am typing as i go.

I then used the name manage, refering to the formula in the first cell of the list

```
=Sheet1!$G$2:INDEX(Sheet1!$G$2:$G$220,COUNTIF(Sheet1!$G$2:$G$220,"?*"))
```

I have then writen this in the ListFillRange in the properties of my combo box.

It works fine for one, but once i had made the second one and selected the site the first one will no longer let me search through.
I have used the same formulas on both but they originate from different sheets to see if this fixed the problem however that was unsuccessful. (the boxes are on different sheets) When i click on the next sheet after using the box on the first sheet, it still shows part of it as if it is crashing. 
The boxes are independent so I'm not sure what to do next as i need to add another 3 on separate sheets. 
I am also using this code for each box

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "MList"
Me.ComboBox1.DropDown
End Sub
```

and similar for the other button but with a different range.

Comment: please post code behind comboboxes, since you used the `vba` tag. If no vba is involved remove that tag.

Comment: try using different names for you Combo Boxes (ComboBox_1 and ComboBox_2 for example).

Comment: thanks but I've tried that and it doent solve it.

Comment: Can you try omitting the `Me.ComboBox1.DropDown` ?

Comment: Tried that too! Sadly didn't make any difference

Comment: the `"MList"` is a predefined range that has the 220 sites ?

Comment: Is your combo box an ***ActiveX Control*** or a ***Form Control***. If it is the first one, try referencing the sheet it is located in using `ActiveSheet.ComboBox_1` **every time** you try to access it. The same goes for the other ones

Comment: Btw, why are you setting the `ListFillRange` whenever it changes ? 
This means that whenever the selection changes, it will reset the  `ListFillRange`

Comment: The Mlist comes from a a sheet that i has made so the combo box can be searchable instead of scrolling through 220 sites. Could the 'ListFillRange' be the problem?

Comment: I'm using an active X control box, where would i put the reference?

Comment: In the VB Editor, put the code for each combo box in its corresponding worksheet module. And instead of `ComboBox_1.ListFillRange` or `Me.ComboBox_1.Dropdown`, use `ActiveSheet.ComboBox_1.DropDown`. You should also investigate the `ListFillRange`. You said you have issues only from the second one. Was the first one working as you wanted? Try deleting the other combo boxes and leave only the first one. Then Test is to make sure it works properly. If it does, then that means the problem does not come from the `ListFillRange`

Comment: They both are technically working however if i use one, the other one breaks. It doesnt matter which way wrong i use them

Comment: Okay, so it is not a `ListFillRange` issue. we can cross that out. did you try putting the code in each worksheet and using ActiveSheet?

Comment: Can you try this : First, execute the code of combox1 manually, then execute the code combo_box2 manually. And let me know.

Comment: Manually as in pressing play when in VBA? Sorry i'm quite new to this so sorry for all my questions!

Comment: Yes. You put the cursor with the code and press F5 or play :)

Comment: Yes i tried using the Activesheet but it came up with the debugger is this the correct way? `ComboBox_2.ListFillRange = "MList"
ActiveSheet.ComboBox_2.DropDown`

Comment: Yeah, doing it manually doesnt make any difference

Comment: okay, let's check about your list 
Can you use the address of your sites liste instead of its name ? 
`ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "=$A$1:$A$200"` (applied for both combo_box codes)

Comment: @Josie you almost got it. `ActiveSheet.ComboBox_2.ListFillRange = "MList"` and `ActiveSheet.ComboBox_2.DropDown`. What do you mean exactly by *"it came up with the debugger"*?

Comment: when i change my code to that and pressed play, i get a run time error, telling me 'object doesn't support this property or method' and asks me to end or debug

Comment: why don't you search for your information first and then add the results to the combobox? Firsty, you won't have to add 220 sites to a Combobox and secondly you'll find the results much faster...

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use VBA for this, the Change Events specifically, if you just want to use and fill the combo boxes with Named Ranges.

The scenario I think you try to do is:

- Create Named Ranges that will be the source of your combobox:
  Fill the range with your data, select the range, Right Click, Select Define Name and give the range a name. MList in your case I believe.
- Create Combobox:
  Goto Developer Tab, Insert in your case ActiveX ComboBox, Draw it on your sheet, right click the ComboBox, select properties, find ListFillRange in properties and enter the name of the Named Range you created in step one
- Repeat for Combobox 2, with the same or a different Named Range depending on what you try to do
- Leave Design Mode

Boths Comboboxes can now be used to type in what you are looking for.

If this is not what you tried to do, please try edit your question and in detail try to explain what you try to do and what you like to accomplish by doing so.

Comment: I have already done these steps, i shall reword my question as i think it could be the range i am trying to use as i want my drop down list to be searchable.

Comment: Still ... why are you using the Change Event @Josie ? Can you elaborate on what your idea is behind that?

Comment: I'm sorry i don't understand what you mean by Change Event?

Comment: You put your code in the Change Event (the event that is triggered when the Combo Box changed, called ComboBox1_Change). 

That event, the Change Event it is called, happens every time the Combo Box changes. I don't think this is the logical place to put code such as changing the ListFillRange. 

For more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836326.aspx